# Standard notation for an integer range

Tags: notation, integers

The following are standard notations for intervals of $\mathbb{R}$; $$[a,b]\qquad(a,b)\qquad[a,b)\qquad (a,b],$$where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is there some kind of succinct equivalent notation for integer ranges?
That is, a standard shorthand notation for $$\{i\}_{i = a}^{b},$$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If not, then I can define my own notation, maybe $R(a,b)$ where $R$ is for 'range', or similar. If there is a standard, I would prefer to use this.

Comment: $\{a,\dots,b\}$ or even $a,\dots,b$

Comment: Probably $a, a+1,\dots,b$, with or without curly brackets. People usually understand that if $a=b$ then the set only has one element

Comment: If your situation deals with both real and integer intervals, you can always say $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, $\{a,\dots,b\}$ is generally accepted to mean the integers from $a$ to $b$ inclusive.

$[n]$, however, is even more commonly used in combinatorics to denote $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and the general case may simply be denoted in the same way as a closed range, $[a,b]$, *where the immediate context deals with integers.*

Comment: Hmm OK, using $[a,b]$ for integers feels uncomfortable to me, but it would make sense within my context.

Comment: As an aside, (*in combinatorics*) $[n]$ for some authors might instead represent $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$... but the point is that $[n]$ is the "prototypical $n$-element set" and what matters most about it is that it has $n$ elements in it, not necessarily whether or not $0$ was included.  Statements involving $[n]$ almost always work for either definition with very few examples where it really matters.  For example, when counting functions $[n]\to [m]$ the number of functions will be $m^n$ in both interpretations.